# How to disable Redis RDB and AOF?

Tags: redis

How to completely disable RDB and AOF?
I don't care about Persistence and want it to be in mem only.

I have already commented out the:

```
#save 900 1
#save 300 10
#save 60 10000
```

But this did not help and I see that Redis still tries to write to disk.
I know that Redis wants to write to disk because I get this error: "Failed opening .rdb for saving: Permission denied"

I don't care about the error, because I want to disable the Persistence altogether.

Comment: Could you add some more details about your environment?

Comment: Single box, CentOS 7, Redis 2.8.19

Answer (score 110, accepted):

If you want to change the redis that is running, log into the redis, and

**disable the aof**:

```
config set appendonly no
```

**disable the rdb**:

```
config set save ""
```

If you want to make these changes effective after restarting redis, using

```
config rewrite
```

to make these changes to redis conf file.

If your redis have not started, just make some changes to redis.conf,

```
appendonly no
save ""
```

make sure there are no sentences like "save 60 1000" after the upper sentences, since the latter would rewrite the former.

Comment: For me, even after doing this the persistance was there always. So, I manually deleted appendonly.aof and dump.rdb I restarted the redis-server, now the persistence is not happening.

Comment: This happened for me also. I disabled writing by commenting out all save lines. However, a dump.rdb file still existed in /var/lib/redis. Every time the redis server started this outdated file was read. Removing the file solved this, of course.

Comment: When using Redis cluster with Sentinel removing `*rdb` files is a must if you still can see see:

    rdb_bgsave_in_progress: 1

Answer (score 6):

**Update: please look at Fibonacci's answer. Mine is wrong, although it was accepted.**

---

Commenting the "dbfilename" line in redis.conf should do the trick.

Comment: This is not true, commenting that line will only fall back on a default location for that file. @fibonacci answer is the correct one.

Comment: Hats off for redirecting your accepted answer to the actually correct one.

Comment: i did take a look at Fibonacci's number, but all it gave me was 13 21 34