# How to disable persistence with redis?

Tags: redis

I was wondering how to disable presistence in redis. There is mention of the possibility of doing this here: http://redis.io/topics/persistence. I mean it in the exact same sense as described there. Any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I found it surprising, if not annoying, that there's no instructions on the official website on this nor there's a lot of information on internet about this (See that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19581059/misconf-redis-is-configured-to-save-rdb-snapshots has much more votes and is better documented than this). Overall considering that Redis is often used as a non-persistent database.

Answer (score 169, accepted):

To disable **all** data persistence in Redis do the following in the `redis.conf` file:

1. Disable AOF by setting the `appendonly` configuration directive to `no` (it is the default value). like this:

   ```
   appendonly no
   ```
2. Disable RDB snapshotting by commenting all of the `save` configuration directives (there are 3 that are defined by default) and explicitly disabling saving:

   ```
   #save 900 1
   #save 300 10
   #save 60 10000
   save ""
   ```

After change, make sure you restart Redis to apply them.

Alternatively, you can use the [`CONFIG SET`](http://redis.io/commands/config-set) command to apply these changes during runtime (just make sure you also do a [`CONFIG REWRITE`](http://redis.io/commands/config-rewrite) to persist the changes).

Note: depending on your Redis' version, there are other tweaks that prevent Redis from accessing the disk for replication-related tasks.

Comment: redis> config set auto-aof-rewrite-percentage 0

Comment: I have configured my Redis to not save data to disk by commenting out the three `save` directives. I can see that it no longer periodically snapshots the data. However, I am still seeing a .rdb file written to disk whenever I shutdown my server. Could it be created anyway, perhaps due to the failover process?

Comment: To actually make this effective, you could use the commands listed here to do it via cli: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34736871/2904315
Or you could just change the redis.conf file as explained in this answer and then restart the service with: `systemctl restart redis`

Comment: In linux, the `redis.conf` file located in `/etc/redis/redis.conf`

Comment: Also don't forget to delete any existing `*.rdb` files created by default config. E.g. in my case after commenting `save` lines, I also had to delete `/var/lib/redis/dump.rdb` before reboot.

Answer (score 99):

If you want to avoid playing with `redis.conf` (dev/test environments), you can do it through the command line with

`redis-server --save "" --appendonly no`

(tested with redis server `3.2.6` and `5.0.5`)

Comment: Are you sure the `--appendonly no` is necessary? Isn't it off by default?

Comment: Could be true. But it certainly doesn't hurt to add it there, just to be on the safe side, what we want is to disable all types of persistence ;)

Comment: hmm, didn't work for me on Windows 10 in WSL (Ubuntu 16)

Comment: @JamesGentes what's the error. It works in my Fedora 29 with Redis 5.0.3, tested it now. Perhaps you need to pass the arguments in a different way in Windows? What's the Redis version? `redis-server --help` could perhaps give some insight

Comment: Hi @Kostis, it's redis 3.0.6 :-/ which may be why. But I was able to just run the separate config commands to get it working, so no biggie. Thx for the follow up on a 2yr old solution :)

Comment: ah yes, the version must be the issue. No worries, i opened SO and your message popped up :)

Comment: Works on version 5.0.5 too.

Answer (score 32):

As AOF (appendonly) is disabled by default, there is only one thing that is to be done for disabling persistence without ***redis service restart*** is to disable **save** configuration.

For disabling it on runtime and verifying run below commands

**Check current save configuration**

```
pawan@devops:~$ redis-cli config get save
1) "save"
2) "900 1 300 10 60 10000"
```

Same setting will be present in redis.conf file as well

```
pawan@devops:~$ grep -w 'save' /etc/redis/redis.conf | grep -v '#'
save 900 1
save 300 10
save 60 10000
```

**Disable save configuration**

```
pawan@devops:~$ redis-cli config set save ""
OK
```

Modify redis.conf file with the new **save** configuration so that the configuration remains permanent on redis service restarts

```
root@ip-172-16-3-114:~# redis-cli config rewrite
OK
```

**Confirm the new save configuration**

```
pawan@devops:~$ redis-cli config get save
1) "save"
2) ""
```

Now if you will scan the redis.conf file for **save** configuration there won't be any results

```
pawan@devops:~$ grep -w 'save' /etc/redis/redis.conf | grep -v '#'  
pawan@devops:~$
```

Answer (score 9):

For RDB snapshotting you can disable it by using

`$ sed -e '/save/ s/^#*/#/' -i /etc/redis/redis.conf && sudo service redis-server restart`

It will comment the save lines in redis.conf and restarts the redis-server