Issues with Redis Embedded Temporary Files Accumulation in Windows using java quarkus
I am using Redis Embedded in my Java Quakrus tests with the following
dependency: <dependency> <groupId>it.ozimov</groupId> <artifactId>embedded-redis</artifactId> <version>0.7.3</version> <scope>test</scope> </dependency>
After running my tests, I noticed that the storage space on my Windows machine was decreasing significantly. Upon investigation, I found a files named like RedisQFork_22904.dat located in
C:\Users\UserHK\AppData\Local\Redis. Deleting this files restored the disk space.
Here’s the relevant part of my Redis setup:
@BeforeAll public static void setUp() throws Exception {redisServer = RedisServer.builder().port(6379).setting("maxmemory 128mb").setting("maxmemory-policy allkeys-lru").setting("appendonly no").setting("save \"\"").build();redisServer.start();assertTrue(redisServer.isActive()); }
@AfterAll public static void cleanUp() {if (redisServer != null) {redisServer.stop();}}
Any advice or solutions would be greatly appreciated! How can I ensure that temporary files like RedisQFork_*.dat do not accumulate after running my tests? Is there a way to automatically clean them up at the end of the tests?

Quick search reveals: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662131/rediss-huge-files-wont-delete https://github.com/microsoftarchive/redis/issues/83

i'm not installing redis on my windows i'm just using the dependacy redis-embededed with this dependency :
 it.ozimov embedded-redis 0.7.3 test 
